# How does the java compiler determine 'method not applicable'?

Tags: java, bounded-wildcard

When using a wildcards some methods (e.g. `ArrayList.set`) cannot be used and return an error message similar to

> The method set(int, capture#3-of ?) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (int, String)

I have read [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684121/generics-error-not-applicable-for-the-arguments) this is the case and would like to know how this is done. That is how does the compiler know that some methods are applicable (e.g. `List.get(int)`) but others are not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler assgins special tokens (`capture#3-of ?`) to each occurence of wildcard and use regular method applicability rules ([JLS 15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2)).

Since captures of wildcards are not compatilbe with other types and with other captures, "method not applicable" is produced.

Comment: So essentially all methods that have a generic parameters are not allowed?

Comment: Generic methods/methods of generic classes parameterized by wildcards are not allowed. It's clear from the explanation of wildcards you referred to - wildcard means "unknown type", therefore we cannot pass anything as a parameter of that type.

Comment: But a return type parameterized by wildcards is allowed, correct?

Answer (score 3):

All applicable rules are in the [Java Language Specification #15.12](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2).