# Generic method doesn't compile - the method is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, generics

Here is my code. The compiler refuses to compile it :

```
private transient List<? extends Map<String, Object>> donnees;

// ...

public <M extends Map<String, Object>> void addDonnee(M nouvelleDonnee) {
    getDonnees().add(nouvelleDonnee);
}

public List<? extends Map<String, Object>> getDonnees() {
    // ...

    return donnees;
}
```

Why do I get this error ?

> `The method add(capture#4-of ? extends Map<String,Object>) in the type List<capture#4-of ? extends Map<String,Object>> is not applicable for the arguments (M)`

**EDIT**
Here how I solve my problem :

```
private transient List<Map<String, Object>> donnees;

// ...

public void addDonnee(Map<String, Object> nouvelleDonnee) {
    getDonnees().add(nouvelleDonnee);
}

public List<Map<String, Object>> getDonnees() {
    // ...

    return donnees;
}
```

And now the compiler is happy ! :)

Comment: Check the answer of [Jack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684121/generics-error-not-applicable-for-the-arguments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `?` and `M` are subclasses, and may not be castable into each other. Try declaring `donnees`:

```
private transient List<Map<String, Object>> donnees;
```

Answer (score 3):

The `getDonnees` method returns a list of "something" that implements `Map<String,Object>`. It could be a list of `TreeMap`s, or of `HashMap`s for example; there's no way to know.

Since you don't know the exact component type of the list, you can't add anything to it. For example, you could be trying to add a `HashMap` to a list of `TreeMap`.

The two methods should use the same parameter somehow, for example one declared with the class:

```
class SomeClass<M extends Map<String, Object>> {

  public void addDonnee(M nouvelleDonnee) {
    getDonnees().add(nouvelleDonnee);
  }

  public List<M> getDonnees() {
    // ...
    return donnees;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot insert anything into a `List` defined as `List<? extends Foo>`.

This is discussed in a decent level of detail in the [JDK documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) (see the bottom of the page).

Comment: Do you mean I must create a class like this `FooList extends ArrayList<Foo>` ?

Comment: The solution from [Dukelink](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18379657/474189) may work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Java is complaining because it doesn't know that the types of `donnees`, `addDonnee` and `getDonnees` are the same. The one could be a `List<HashMap<String, Object>>`, while the others can be a `List<TreeMap<String, Object>>`, which are not compatible (you can't add a `HashMap` to a `List<TreeMap>` and vice versa).

You can add a generic parameter to the class instead:

```
public class SomeClass<T extends Map<String, Object>>
{
  private transient List<T> donnees;

  public void addDonnee(T nouvelleDonnee) {
      getDonnees().add(nouvelleDonnee);
  }

  public List<T> getDonnees() {
      return donnees;
  }
}
```