# Implement Chain of Responsibility using Generics

Tags: java, generics, chain-of-responsibility

So I want to implements the Chain of Responsibility but use generics, with an upper bound.

```
public abstract class Handler<C extends Command> {

    private Handler<? extends Command> successor;

    public Handler(Handler<? extends Command> successor) {
        this.successor = successor;
    }

    public final String handle(C cmd) {
        if (canHandle(cmd)) {
            return doHandle(cmd);
        } else {
            // The method doHandle(capture#3-of ? extends Command) in the type Handler<capture#3-of ? extends Command>
            // is not applicable for the arguments (C)
            return successor.doHandle(cmd);
        }
    }

    protected abstract boolean canHandle(C cmd);

    protected abstract String doHandle(C cmd);

}

abstract class Command {
    public String getParamBase() {
        return "base";
    }
}

class CommandTypeOne extends Command {
    public String getTypeOneParam() {
        return "ParamTypeOne";
    }
}

class CommandTypeTwo extends Command {
    public String getTypeTwoParam() {
        return "ParamTypeTwo";
    }
}
```

Sure I could have the class non-generic, and have Command as parameter everywhere, and that would work. But I don't want to use casting in the doHandle method to pass to the corresponding subtype of Command. I want to have a Handler for each of the subtypes, generic, and just chain them.

The issue I get is: **The method doHandle(capture#3-of ? extends Command) in the type Handler is not applicable for the arguments (C)**

Why if C extends Command?

Comment: At which line you have the error?

Comment: Do you need to use generics in this case?  All objects that extend `Command` have an is-a relationship to `Command`.  Will your `Handler` be expecting all `Commands` to be of the same sub-type?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684121/generics-error-not-applicable-for-the-arguments

Comment: @gurghet you can see the error in the code too, I put it there as a comment also. PaulProgrammer that is the thing, the handlers are not of the same subtype, I want to have one handler for each subtype, the subtype will be passed as generic. I want to use generic to avoid using instanceof and casting. Thanks for the link Mick will read it.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine what would happen if you replaced `Command` by `Animal` (superclass of `Cat` and `Dog`).

The signature of the `successor` reference says it can handle some type of Animal, say only Cats. On the other hand, the `cmd` parameter of the `handle()` method also says that the command to handle can be of any other subtype of Animal - here, `Dog` could be a valid type.

You see that nothing guarantees that the `successor` handler will be able to manage the particular type of command, so the compiler gets somewhat angry.

Comment: Handler<Cat> successor = new Handler<Cat>(null);
Handler<Dog> dogHandler = new Handler<Dog>(successor);
The method canHandle, doHandle, handle in DogHandler handles Dog
The method canHandle, doHandle, handle in successor handles Cat

Not sure I follow.

Comment: If your instance is declarede as a `Handler<Dog>`, the type variable `C` will be `Dog` in the signature of the `handle()` method. But if its `successor` field is of type `Handler<Cat>`, you have a problem.`

Comment: yes but why, they are both Animal. I don't see that much difference between <? extends Command> and <T extends Command>

Comment: Because your type signatures don't say "I can handle any Animal", they say "I can handle only one type of animal", and the precise type of animal declared by `Handler` can be different from that of its successor.

Answer (score 1):

Your field successor could hold an instance which is really a `Handler<CommandTypeOne>` because it can hold everything as long as `C extends Command`. The signature of its `doHandle` method would be `String doHandle(CommandTypeOne cmd)`. If you then call `successor.doHandle()` in `handle()` you would pass a parameter that is only guaranteed to be a `Command` but not a `CommandTypeOne`.

Maybe you should have a look into [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs). Producer extends - Consumer super. You can google it. In your case your doHandle method is a consumer and you should use super instead of extends.

I would probably go without a generic in this case. Put Command where C is now. This allows to pass Commands and Subtypes to a handler chain. To allow a handler to distinguish commands you could establish an id for commands possibly with a String or int. Or you could use instanceof to allow a handler to check for a specific subtype of command. Both solutions are not very object oriented.

At this point your Command feels like a data container with different content depending on your subtype.

Comment: flex my PECS? I've heard about it some time ago already forgot will try to look into it.

Comment: I think you're saying a similar thing to what Olivier Croisier is saying, and I do understand your explanation perfectly. But after reading a bit about PECS I don't see how should I modify the code properly. Even if I make the error dissapear, a Handler<CommandTypeOne> is not a subtype of a Handler<Command> and I cannot create the handler chain...

Answer (score 0):

Here your Handler class

```
//In your case 'C extends Command' in class declaration will be enough 
public abstract class Handler<C extends Command> { 

private Handler<C> successor;

public Handler(Handler<C> successor) {
    this.successor = successor;
}

public final String handle(C cmd) {
    if (canHandle(cmd)) {
        return doHandle(cmd);
    } else {
        // The method doHandle(capture#3-of ? extends Command) in the type Handler<capture#3-of ? extends Command>
        // is not applicable for the arguments (C)
        return successor.doHandle(cmd);
    }
}

protected abstract boolean canHandle(C cmd);

protected abstract String doHandle(C cmd);
```

}

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong byt Isn't this exactly what I'm trying to avoid? Let's say we have one Handler<CommandTypeOne> this means it's successor will be of able to handle only <CommandTypeOne> according to the constructor and the signature of the successor field.

Comment: Does it make sense to have Handler<CommandTypeOne> with successor like  Handler<CommandTypeTwo>?
If chain request will be CommandTypeOne it should be handled by successor  of type Handler<CommandTypeOne> only, isn't it? 
Or i don't understand clearly what do you actually want to do.

Comment: Each handler should handle a subtype. Try creating a class HandlerTypeOne extends Handler<CommandTypeOne> {......} now look at it's constructor. It accepts Hander<CommandTypeOne> like you say it doesn't make sense to have 2 handlers handle the same type of request.

Comment: Oh, i finally got your point, and that what you gonna do is not possible using java jenerics.

Comment: I think I've realized just that, answering to Sponiro's answer. Thank you very much for your time sir.